# Label as header in Category Page Blogger

Tags: javascript, html, blogger

I have a website in which I can show posts with all the same labels. Is there a way to make the label as the header when showing all the posts with the same label. 

For example, on https://newsotuniverse.blogspot.ca/search/label/astrophysics is there a way to make the header 'Astrophysics' or on https://newsotuniverse.blogspot.ca/search/label/engineering to make the header 'Engineering'?

I would like to put the name of the label (the header) in this:

```
 <b:if cond='data:navMessage'>
  <div class='status-msg-wrap'>
    <div class='status-msg-body'>
      <data:label.url/>


      //label header here plz


      </div>
    <div class='status-msg-border'>
      <div class='status-msg-bg'>
        <div class='status-msg-hidden'><data:navMessage/></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style='clear: both;'/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace `//label header here plz` with `<data:blog.searchLabel/>`, this data Tag returns the current filtered label.

It cloud look, like this:

```html
  ...
  <div class='status-msg-wrap'>
    <div class='status-msg-body'>
      ...
      <span style="text-transform: capitalize;"><data:blog.searchLabel/></span>
     ...
    </div>
  <div class='status-msg-border'>
  <div class='status-msg-bg'>
    <div class='status-msg-hidden'><data:navMessage/></div>
  </div>
</div>
...
```

> The wrapping `span` is set only so that we can set the css property `text-transform` to `capitalize`, since I Like my headers capitalized.